# What method to detect structural breaks on time series?

Tags: r

I have two lists of price (stock) and I need a method to detect if there are structural breaks inside those series. What method can I use?

For each serie I have around 600 prices (daily).

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by structural breaks?

Comment: Hi! Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_break

Answer (score 7):

Look at the [strucchange](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/index.html) package in R. From the description:

> Testing, monitoring and dating structural changes in (linear)
>   regression models. strucchange features tests/methods from the
>   generalized fluctuation test framework as well as from the F test
>   (Chow test) framework. This includes methods to fit, plot and test
>   fluctuation processes (e.g., CUSUM, MOSUM, recursive/moving estimates)
>   and F statistics, respectively. It is possible to monitor incoming
>   data online using fluctuation processes. Finally, the breakpoints in
>   regression models with structural changes can be estimated together
>   with confidence intervals. Emphasis is always given to methods for
>   visualizing the data.