# How to detect an unknown number of segments, each to be fitted with an unknown parametric curve/surface equation?

Tags: parameterization, image-segmentation, timeseries-segmentation

Let's say I have a set of points (possibly noisy) in an N-dimensional space that represent an arbitrary number of curved segments, each segment having an arbitrary type of curve. See the 2D sample below, borrowed from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156100/how-can-i-programmatically-detect-segments-of-a-data-series-to-fit-with-differen):

[image: Sample curve]

To a human being, this curve obviously consists of 3 distinct segments: a sine wave, a linear portion, and an exponential segment at the end.

Is there a fully programmatic and autonomous solution for determining what each segment is? Plus the real kicker - can this problem be solved in 3D, where it's an arbitrary number of surface segments, with each segment being of arbitrary surface types (e.g. planes, conical surfaces, surfaces with sinusoidal oscillations, etc.)?

Comment: The previous question linked was from 8 years ago. With the advances in ML, thought it's worth re-asking. Happy for this to be marked as duplicate and/or merged with the other question if the community thinks that's best.

Comment: Not gonna happen.

Comment: @user2974951 perhaps... but look at the state of the art image segmentation in the autonomous driving and computer vision industry! I feel like a solution must be within reach, even if it's non-deterministic one